# how to add a class to a a-tag based on a listelement

Tags: jquery

I have a function so when a listelement is klicked some stuff happens. At the end it should add a class to the a-tag of the selected listelement.

I tried

```
$("li").click(function (event) {
    //do some stuff
    //
    //

    $(this).("a").addClass("aktiv");
    $(this).attr("href").addClass("aktiv");
    $(this).each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).addClass("aktiv");
    });
    $(this).children().addClass("aktiv");
});
```

but it is not working as expected.

can someone help with the right synthax?

Comment: ``$(this).find("a").addClass("yourClass")``

Comment: Wow! thanks it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $("li").click(function (event) {
        //do some stuff
        //
        //

        $(this).find("a").addClass("aktiv");

    });
```

// or you can do as

```
 $("li").click(function (event) {
    //do some stuff
    //
    //


    $(this).each(function(index, element) {
        element.find('a').addClass("aktiv");
    });

});
```